# Use Login method before test

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, pom

I use POM pattern in Selenium tests.
To run tests OpCreate and OpEdit, a user should be logged in.
I have positive test for Login, but how to run Login every time OpCreate and OpEdit tests are run? Probably, there are other solutions?

```
public class SignInPage {
    //some @FindBy here

    public void makeLogin(String email, String password) {
        emailLogin.sendKeys(email);
        passwordLogin.sendKeys(password);
        loginButton.click();
}

public class LoginTest extends UiTestBase {

    @Test()
    private void UicorrectLogin() {
        //init user and pass

       loginPage.makeLogin(user, pass);
       //check for login
       Assert.assertEquals(true, menuPage.getMenu().isDisplayed());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    private void tearDown() {
    }
}


public class OpTest extends UiTestBase {

    @Test()
    private void OpCreate() {
        //some Op test
        }

    @Test()
    private void OpEdit() {
        //some Op test
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a @BeforeTest and make login in that method in the LoginTest and OpTest class.

```
public class LoginTest extends UiTestBase {

SignInPage signInPage = new SignInpage();

@BeforeTest
public void loginBeforeTest(){
    signInPage.makeLogin(user, pass);
}
@Test()
private void UicorrectLogin() {
    //init user and pass

   loginPage.makeLogin(user, pass);
   //check for login
   Assert.assertEquals(true, menuPage.getMenu().isDisplayed());
}

@AfterMethod
private void tearDown() {
}
}


public class OpTest extends UiTestBase {

SignInPage signInPage = new SignInpage();

@BeforeTest
public void loginBeforeTest(){
    signInPage.makeLogin(user, pass);
}
@Test()
private void OpCreate() {
    //some Op test
    }

@Test()
private void OpEdit() {
    //some Op test
    }
}
```